# Moderator primary vote count fetch returns error

Tags: bug, vote-count, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who can split the votes in the primary election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election)

I don't have enough rep to view vote counts on questions, but on the election page, I can click on the vote numbers for candidates.

However, when I click the vote numbers, for a split second, I see some text that reads "Loading", then I get an orange box saying:

> An error occurred during vote count fetch

This is a bug, since you do not need 1000 rep to view the  candidate vote counts in the primary; see [Who can split the votes in the primary election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election)

Comment: +1 This happens to me on SuperUser but not StackOverflow. Of course, I don't have enough rep. on SuperUser to split votes, but there shouldn't be an error message.

Comment: This isn't really a dupe.  This is a bug, and the marked dupe explains WHY it's a bug -- the intended behavior isn't occurring (it was apparently fixed but is broken again).  Those who can vote should not get this error message.