# Who can split the votes in the primary election

Tags: support, election, vote-count

Is this restricted to 1k users?  Or can anyone split the vote counts in the primary election?

Comment: Shoot, all my sockpuppets have over 1k.  You'll have to find someone else...

Comment: @Polly, maybe I should make a few sockpuppets and situate them at strategic rep levels to test this stuff.

Comment: @Justin - I've considered that, but it sounds too much like *work*.

Comment: @Polly, that would be work.

Comment: It wouldn't take too long using bounty. Come to think of it, you could even give the rep *back* after. @Polly

Comment: My SO rep is under 1K.  I consistently get "An error occurred while fetching vote counts." on the candidates.  On normal questions and answers, the cursor does not even change, and nothing happens when I click the vote number.

Comment: @Justin I've tried, but they keep getting endless upvotes. Something about my spectacular answers, I guess

Comment: You say "election" but do you mean "primary"? SF is on the real election and I see no vote counts.

Comment: @Michael, yeah.  That would be a difficult problem to deal with.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76432/moderator-primary-vote-count-fetch-returns-error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vote counts for the primary election will be visible for all who have enough reputation to vote after the next deploy.

Comment: This seems to be broken again (“An error occurred during vote count fetch”): I can see the splits on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary), [SU](http://superuser.com/election/1?tab=primary), [AU](http://askubuntu.com/election/1?tab=primary) (all +0/-0 since there was no primary) but not [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary) or [English](http://english.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary). This is consistent with a 1k rep threshold.

Comment: Confirming the breakage. I can't see the splits for Gaming but I can for SO and English.

Comment: [Still broken.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112432/viewing-vote-counts-for-election-candidates-gives-me-an-error)

Comment: Still broken for myself as well, and I have 150+ rep on SO.

Comment: You must be an established user: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user

Comment: @GeoffDalgas That directly contradicts your answer.  Is it intended to be voters (150+ rep) or established users (1000+ rep) who can see the vote breakdowns in elections?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas So which of these is the actual limit? FWIW, I can click on the number, but it returns an error.

Comment: Confirmed that it is broken for voters (150+ rep) on SO.

Answer (score 8):

A less than 1k reputation account is getting "An error occurred while fetching vote counts." when trying to click on the reputation.

However, the page says that:

> There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down vote per candidate. **The candidate vote scores are all public.** Initial voting should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most electable.

So, maybe it's made public but the callback function is not updated and <1k users are not getting it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have < 1k on SO and I'm not seeing *any* vote counts at all.