# Election primary vote count is no lower than -1

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election, vote-count

There are [currently](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) 2 moderators who have a total vote count of less than 0 during the primary phase. But the total vote count sticks at -1 and is no lower than that. Neal, for example, currently stands at +97/-140 which should give a total vote count of -43.

I remember having seen this during the last elections as well, but I assumed it to be just a bug and I didn't find it important enough to report on meta. But right now, after many elections using the same engine, not only on Stack Overflow, this issue seem still to manifest.

Can we please fix it? Or is this working as designed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

It was decided to be too cruel to display a *person* as having a score less than 0.

> There was talk during the SO election that massively negative scores was unnecessarily demoralizing; the point of the primary is to find the 10 best candidates, not to say "this person is ridiculously awful and deserves hundreds of downvotes" – [Michael Mrozek Feb 8 '11 at 22:13](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/votes-for-moderator-doesnt-drop-below-0#comment4495_1737)

See also: [the chat where Grace and Rebecca say this is intentional](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/475929#475929)

Comment: Cruel how? Either you show the actual voting balance, or you don't show any balance IMO.

Comment: It's also easily circumvented by being able to see the tallies (1K+, I believe).

Comment: @Makoto The vote split should be available to [everyone who can vote in the election](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election).

Comment: @AnnaLear is it? I get a "could not fetch votes" error, I assumed it was because I'm under 1k

Comment: @BenBrocka Ergh. Nevermind. The comments on Dalgas' answer seem to contradict the answer. 1,000 it is.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. The -1 which I'm seeing instead of 0 is of course my own vote. I'd however expect to see this being explained somewhere in the elections page, e.g. the yellow box in the right column, but that's a different matter.