# Voters with less than 1K reputation can't see election Primaries vote counts

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, election, vote-count

Apparently [Anna Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135576/election-primary-vote-count-is-no-lower-than-1#comment378247_135577) and Shog9 seem to think you can fetch vote counts for Primaries even if you don't have 1k; this [seems to be the official intent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76472/166936) but [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election#comment291999_76472) contradicts that, and regardless of intent, on the election primaries page, I *can* click to attempt to fetch vote counts, but I get an error upon trying.

If all eligible voters are supposed to be able to view the voting results...we can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix for this <s>will go out in the next build</s> is being deployed literally as I write this.