# Election candidates with more than 100 downvotes are not showing the minus sign against the number of downvotes

Tags: support, status-bydesign, election

On the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) if you click on the number of votes it will show you the breakdown of up and down votes in the same way that question up and down votes can be viewed.

But if the candidate has more than 100 down votes then the down votes count is missing the minus sign:

[image]

Comment: This is on purpose, I remember from a past election but I'm too lazy to search and link to a source.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135576/175248 - it was by design.

Comment: @gnat no, this is not duplicate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The +/- prefix is hidden for counts larger than 99. Your screenshot also lacks the "+" before the upvote count. Compare with these two-digit counts:

[image]

Comment: Fair enough then, I guess they ran out of screen space for the extra +/-

Comment: i was wandering why some candidates have `200` downvotes while some have `-80`...