# Negative number of down votes in Elections

Tags: support, voting, election

When viewing the number of up votes and down votes on the [elections page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1), I see some people seem to have a negative number of down votes.  How is this possible?  What does this mean?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135584/147650) (as mentioned in the current answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a vote count is in double digits it has +/- in front of it (for up/downvotes respectively, obviously). When they get to three digits or more, the sign is dropped. That's just the way it is meant to be. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135584/172958) from a few days ago. Note that this happens on all vote counts across all sites, not just elections.

Comment: Wow, I've never noticed that before. Thanks.