# Large down-vote count doesn't display negative sign

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, down-votes, score

Consider the question [Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99062/168244):

[image]

The large number of down-votes displays as 199 rather than a score of -199.

This is clearly unintentional (and unfortunate for questions that possess such voting!), but can this be corrected?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135584/election-candidates-with-more-than-100-downvotes-are-not-showing-the-minus-sign

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is, in fact, intentional.

There isn't a space next to the 199. Look at the vote breakdown for the [highest voted question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) - there is no plus on the upvotes:

> [image: upvotes have no plus!!!]

Anyone who clicks on the score to see the breakdown **knows** that the top (green) is the upvotes and the bottom one (red) is downvotes (the colors are of course also intentional - green/good red/bad). I say everyone, as this is a privilege - by the time you get it, you know the difference.

The breakdown area also has a tooltip - in your example, is says `42 up / 199 down`, so the information is also there.

Comment: Why print *some* signs, then?

Comment: I'll have to give this a -1, even if the first sentence is, indeed, factually correct. Intentional or not, there's *plenty* of space for the signs, especially since the column will just resize if the vote count gets too wide. I can sort of understand omitting the needless + signs to avoid unnecessary layout changes, but there's no point in leaving out - signs (since the unexpanded vote count has a - in sign front of it anyway).