# Should there be a point system related to behavior?

Tags: discussion

I've come across impolite behavior - as I can imagine many have.

Except for the "flag" option, should there be a point system (as in driving) to assign points for impolite/inappropriate behavior.

It may keep people more in line, if not used incorrectly.

Comment: Just edit or flag. And if the problem is more severe, use a custom "other" flag to explain it to a moderator. There is no need for penalty points. When it gets out of hand, a suspension if far more effective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's not very nice itself.

I assume your system would have to be public in order for it to work, which would only encourage vindicative behaviour, which is what you seem to want to engage in. This has no place anywhere on Stack Exchange or in wider society.

If you have a problem with a comment flag it. If it's genuinely offensive flag it as "offensive", if it's a little impolite then flag it as "other" and say what you think. If certain people are continually getting flagged it's noticed and moderators can warn people *privately* and suspend them if necessary.

Comment: Well, it could be argued that "Flagging" is a two edged sword... though it helps inform the moderators of inappropriate behavior how can you be sure people don't use that vindictively as well? Secondly, your reference to vindictiveness was not part of my question... I was asking about the merits of how it may have been an incentive for keeping people in line - `it's not nice to put words in my mouth!`. Finally, I didn't think many people would abuse it for other reasons, but based in your answer I'm sure they would...

Comment: You can't be sure people don't abuse flagging but there's always someone to double check and the results never get displayed. My reference to vindictiveness doesn't have to be part of your question, it's certainly part of my answer though as that's what I think it would encourage... and lastly you'll notice I wrote _"seem"_ :-).

Answer (score 7):

No, this system itself is rather rude. Quoting [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135577/178438)

> It was decided to be too cruel to display a person as having a score less than 0.

More or less the same principle applies here: Assigning "bad points" to the user is sort of cruel and is rather mean. It opens the window for prejudices and other things. And also will help ostracize a user who probably is slightly abrasive but has a chance to improve.

The number of flags a user has received is logged and visible to moderators. Just like the number and details of suspensions (which, incidentally, are kept private for the same reasons)

The mods have the necessary tools to deal with this already. If you flag something, they will deal with it and multiple incidences (or one particularly bad incidence) will incite a warning or a temporary suspension. This seems good enough to me; there's no need to gamify the system of keeping it civil.