# Viewing vote counts for election candidates gives me an error

Tags: bug, election, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moderator primary vote count fetch returns error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76432/moderator-primary-vote-count-fetch-returns-error)
>   [Who can split the votes in the primary election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election)

I get this error when click on the vote total to see the count:

[image: screenshot]

I would assume it's due to the fact that my SO rep is a hilarious 160, and therefore I don't have the view vote count privilege [you get at 1000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user).  But according to [Who can split the votes in the primary election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/who-can-split-the-votes-in-the-primary-election), everyone who can vote (150+ rep) should be able to see election vote counts, and this error shouldn't occur.

Comment: I like rediscovering all the annoyances we found last election

Comment: @MichaelMrozek That question is a bug report and incorrectly closed as a dupe of the question asking what *should* happen (but isn't).  Given that, one of the bug reports should be open ... how about mine, since it already is? :P

Comment: @Matthew Better your question than mine, since I can no longer repro this :P

Comment: OK, looking at the timestamps I understand better why the other was closed, but the intended-behavior one still isn't a bug report and it's outdated.  I'd rather see something current that can actually get attention stay open. @Jason Nice work :P